# Why if(count==0) condition does not work in each time? Is it right solving task(generally)?

Tags: c#, if-statement

It works when the event is generated once and after receiving a zero, the phrase is displayed: "Zero received - event generation is completed". But if the event is generated twice, the phrase - "Zero received - event generation is completed" is not output.

Task.
Create an application where the event generator can generate three different events. Event receivers act as subscribers to the post office and can forward information to each other using the generator as a mailbox. At the same time, they indicate the number (from 1 to 3) of the next receiver and some integer that
is transmitted to the receiver. This transmission cycle continues until one of the receivers specifies the number zero as the receiver. In this case, the application shuts down. When the application is started, the first mail notification is always received from the generator by the first receiver. To address and transmit information, use the second argument of the event handler.

```
using System;

namespace DelegateEvents
{
    class Program
    {
       static int count;
        class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            int handlernumber;
            public int Handlernumber{ get;set; }
            int numb;
            public int Numb { get; set; }
        }

        delegate void MyEventHandler(object source, MyEventArgs e);
        class GenEvent
        {
            public event MyEventHandler Event1;
             public void OnEvent1()
            {
                MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();
                if (Event1 != null)
                {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    e.Numb = rand.Next(1, 8);
                    e.Handlernumber = 1;
                    Event1(this, e); 
                }

            }
            public event MyEventHandler Event2;
            public void OnEvent2()
            {
                MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();
                if (Event2 != null)
                {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    e.Handlernumber = 2;
                    e.Numb = rand.Next(1, 8);
                        Event2(this, e);
                }

            }
            public event MyEventHandler Event3;
            public void OnEvent3()
            {
                MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();
                if (Event3 != null)
                {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    e.Handlernumber = 3;
                    e.Numb = rand.Next(1, 8);
                    Event3(this, e);   
                }
            }
        }
        class FirstEventHandler
        {
            public void Handler1(object source, MyEventArgs e) 
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                Console.WriteLine("Event happend:"   + e.Handlernumber+ " Got number:"+ e.Numb+ " Source:" + source);
                e.Handlernumber = rand.Next(0,4);
                count = e.Handlernumber;
            }
            
        }
        class SecondEventHandler
        {
            public void Handler2(object source, MyEventArgs e)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                Console.WriteLine("Event happend:"   + e.Handlernumber+ " Got number:"+ e.Numb+" Source:" + source);
                e.Handlernumber = rand.Next(0, 4);
                count = e.Handlernumber;
            }
        }
        class ThirdEventHandler
        {
            public void Handler3(object source, MyEventArgs e)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                Console.WriteLine("Event happend:"+e.Handlernumber + " Got number:" + e.Numb+" Source:" + source);
                e.Handlernumber = rand.Next(0, 4);
                count = e.Handlernumber;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GenEvent genEvent = new GenEvent();
            FirstEventHandler firstEventHandler = new FirstEventHandler();
            SecondEventHandler secondEventHandler = new SecondEventHandler();
            ThirdEventHandler thirdEventHandler = new ThirdEventHandler();
            genEvent.Event1 += firstEventHandler.Handler1;
            genEvent.Event2 += secondEventHandler.Handler2;
            genEvent.Event3 += thirdEventHandler.Handler3;
            genEvent.OnEvent1();
            if (count == 0)
            { Console.WriteLine("Zero received - event generation is completed"); }
            else if(count == 1)
            genEvent.OnEvent1();
            else if (count == 2)
            genEvent.OnEvent2();
            else if (count == 3)
            genEvent.OnEvent3(); 
        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main program seems to be missing some kind of loop. It just handles one event and then quits.

Comment: A curious assignment; I'm not sure how it will avoid eventually overflowing the stack if the methods just continually raise an event which calls a method which calls a method that raises an event.. maybe hoping that the addressee hits 0 long before it hits the stack limit.. Anyways, I can't see any repeating mechanism that the events use to transmit a message back to the generator so that it can raise its next event to some other handler; Count is processed once. I also think the assignment insisting the message data be int is asking for trouble; I'd make it a string,distinct from addressee

Comment: @nvoigt In general, events are generated and when a zero is received, the program terminates(as it should be). But the phrase ("Zero received-event generation is completed"); does not always output.

Comment: (From Reading the assignment I was expecting that each event handler implementation would decide on a random addressee trueness call a method on the generator demanding that some message x be transmitted to random addressee y, which the generator then handles by raising an event for that addressee, which calls the deliver, which calls the handler.. etc etc)

Comment: Typo correction: "trueness" => "and then", autocorrect sorry...

Comment: @CaiusJard Is the task solved incorrectly? Should there be one event generator and several handlers that pass messages to each other?

Comment: The assignment says to pass messages via the generator

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you! I will also try to solve the task in a different way, taking into account your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a loop just as nvoigt said.

On your first event handler `genEvent.OnEvent1();` it will modify the count via Event1.
After that, it will continue to the `if(count ==0) ...`, the count then will change again.
However, after the count change, it will not be doing anything.

Then, you might want to have 1 Random object to randomize number. Having multiple random objects tends to generate the same dataset if it has the same order.

Try this:

```
using System;
namespace DelegateEvents
{
  class Program
  {
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static int count;
    class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
      int handlernumber;
      public int Handlernumber { get; set; }
      int numb;
      public int Numb { get; set; }
    }

    delegate void MyEventHandler( object source, MyEventArgs e );
    class GenEvent
    {
      public event MyEventHandler Event1;
      public void OnEvent1()
      {
        MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();
        if( Event1 != null )
        {
          e.Numb = rand.Next( 1, 8 );
          e.Handlernumber = 1;
          Event1( this, e );
        }

      }
      public event MyEventHandler Event2;
      public void OnEvent2()
      {
        MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();
        if( Event2 != null )
        {
          e.Handlernumber = 2;
          e.Numb = rand.Next( 1, 8 );
          Event2( this, e );
        }

      }
      public event MyEventHandler Event3;
      public void OnEvent3()
      {
        MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();
        if( Event3 != null )
        {
          e.Handlernumber = 3;
          e.Numb = rand.Next( 1, 8 );
          Event3( this, e );
        }
      }
    }
    class FirstEventHandler
    {
      public void Handler1( object source, MyEventArgs e )
      {
        var c = rand.Next( 0, 4 );
        Console.WriteLine( "EventHandler1 happend:" + e.Handlernumber + " Got number:" + e.Numb + " Source:" + source + " Count: " + c );
        e.Handlernumber = c;
        count = c;
      }

    }
    class SecondEventHandler
    {
      public void Handler2( object source, MyEventArgs e )
      {
        var c = rand.Next( 0, 4 );
        Console.WriteLine( "EventHandler2 happend:" + e.Handlernumber + " Got number:" + e.Numb + " Source:" + source + " Count: " + c );
        e.Handlernumber = c;
        count = c;
      }
    }
    class ThirdEventHandler
    {
      public void Handler3( object source, MyEventArgs e )
      {
        var c = rand.Next( 0, 4 );
        Console.WriteLine( "EventHandler3 happend:" + e.Handlernumber + " Got number:" + e.Numb + " Source:" + source + " Count: " + c);
        e.Handlernumber = c;
        count = c;
      }
    }
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      GenEvent genEvent = new GenEvent();
      FirstEventHandler firstEventHandler = new FirstEventHandler();
      SecondEventHandler secondEventHandler = new SecondEventHandler();
      ThirdEventHandler thirdEventHandler = new ThirdEventHandler();
      genEvent.Event1 += firstEventHandler.Handler1;
      genEvent.Event2 += secondEventHandler.Handler2;
      genEvent.Event3 += thirdEventHandler.Handler3;
      genEvent.OnEvent1();
      while( true )
      {
        if( count == 0 )
        {
          Console.WriteLine( "Zero received - event generation is completed" );
          return;
        }
        else if( count == 1 )
          genEvent.OnEvent1();
        else if( count == 2 )
          genEvent.OnEvent2();
        else if( count == 3 )
          genEvent.OnEvent3();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you say, in general, the task is solved correctly?

Comment: I think you are the one that should be able to answer that. If this is really what you want or not.

Comment: If you asked me, I think this is what you might want and it always displays Zero received - event generation is completed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I said it wrong. I meant, in your opinion, the task (in general) was solved correctly (except the incorrect operation of the if-construct in the Main method)?Or should there be one event generator and several handlers that pass messages to each other? Thank you very much for your help in solving the problem with the if-construct in the main method.

Comment: @Kosmas for obviously-homework questions, perhaps consider *not* doing people's homework for them; encourage them to think aout how to solve their problem themselves - they'll get more out of it that way. For sure you're not going to get any credit from the supervisor for this one, and when asked "so, tell me how you solved your homework" - "err.. the people on SO wrote it for me" isn't really an answer that will do wonders for the student either

Comment: Technically, it is possible to always pass the `count` parameter. However,  this should be avoided as it will increase the stack. This is not a good practice, but it is possible to do that. So, it depends on your need, do the value is really required to be passed, or it is an individual event that is not related to the previous event.
In your case, it's better to do the loop, so it can loop until forever as long as it does not reach zero.
The problem with the stack is the memory will increase and we don't want that if we don't need it to be stacked.

Comment: @CaiusJard noted.

Comment: @Kosmas I also solved this task in other way. Could you tell me is it good solving? The new solution is above under the heading "Other way to solve the task".

Answer (score 0):

> But the phrase ("Zero received-event generation is completed"); does not always output.

Let's work it through:

You've decided to use static int count to communicate from handler to generator

You call OnEvent1 to kick start things

Event1 handler generates a random int, let's say 3, and it goes in count

Then your if block runs, and `if(count==3)` ensures Event3 handler runs. Let's say it generates and stores 1 in count

Then the program ends because control passes back to the Main method and there is nothing left to do after the if. The control flow exits Main

No message was output

---

Realistically you'll only get a message if an Event1 handler generates count = 0, roughly 25% of the time

Comment: Is the task solved incorrectly(except part with if-statement)? Should there be one event generator and several handlers that pass messages to each other?

Comment: Thank you! I will also try to solve the task in a different way, taking into account your comments.

Comment: An often-used pattern with events is for the object that raises the event to pass itself as one of the event arguments; this could be a simple way to give your event handler subscribers access to the generator

Comment: I solved this  task in other way. Could you tell me is it good solving? The new solution is above under the heading "Other way to solve the task".